# html5 sprite added to canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

After doing a well rounded search online (on here as well) nothing has helped me thus far. 
I want to insert the image sprite I have onto the canvas, but the image has to be bottom of the canvas, above the border of course.    http://jsfiddle.net/LcKZX/1/ My question is: how do I create a sprite on top of the platform (the imgur image I have under: "imageObject.src")?

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="matrixStyle.css"/>
</head>

<title>Lil Teemo</title>

<body onload="draw();">
    <canvas id="tutorial" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="matrixB.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

JS code (this is for the platform which works fine, ignore the code):

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('tutorial');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var x = 0;
        var y = 350;
        var width = 650;
        var height = 50;
        var imageObj = new Image();

          imageObj.onload = function() {
             context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y, width, height);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/dAwfqnv.png?1?3495';
```

CSS code:

```
canvas {
    border: 5px solid black;
    background: #87CEFA;

}

body {
    margin: 5;
    padding: 0;
}
```

How do I insert a sprite onto the canvas? I'll add movements to the sprite after this has been figured out. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I have check your code on on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcKZX/1/) and correct it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LcKZX/4/).

There is an issue of `draw()` is `undefined` and image is not found as path is incorrect.

Comment: The reason the path is incorrect is because I have the platform.png on my computer. I couldn't put it on jsfiddle. 

Everything works besides positioning the sprite on the canvas.

Comment: @user3223207 just upload the image to imgur.com and use a link from there instead

Comment: I just stated the mistake you have done in jsfiddle example. Now you can try same code on your local server where you are easily access all you assets.

Answer (score 0):

- You can either do this by using the **img tag.**. (Which i think you dont want)
  Link: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_drawimage
- For the image Object:
  To get the **image data** for each pixel of a rectangular area on the canvas, we can get the image data object with the **getImageData() method** of the canvas context and then access the pixel data from the data property.  Each pixel in the image data contains four components, a red, green, blue, and alpha component.  There are three common techniques for accessing pixel data with the image data object.
  Iterating over all of the pixels starting from the top left corner to the bottom right corner of the region
  picking out pixel data based on x, y coordinates
  iterating over all of the pixels while keeping track of the x, y coordinates for each pixel.
  This should help you out :

  http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/

Comment: I am using the website you directed me to. The problem is I can't seem to get the sprite character to appear on the canvas. I have 2 sprites. One of them appears and the 2nd one doesn't appear. I can't path the .png files onto jsfiddle to show you what I mean.

Comment: Upload your platform.png here: http://imgur.com/
Then give that link of the image to the imageObj.src in this link: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-get-image-data-tutorial/

And get back to me

Comment: I uploaded the platform on imgur.com, however its not being displayed on jsfiddle for some odd reason.

Comment: Gimme the link for the image u uploaded on imgur.com